# Number in chat user page corner

Tags: support, chat

While browsing chat, I noticed a number in the corner of chat user pages (as shown below).

[image: Number in corner]

I noticed that this was different on other users' pages. For example, above it's 50, on my page it's 24 and on two other pages it's 4.

At first, I thought it was a count of the number of people who'd ignored the user, but that's just me. ***What does it really mean?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the tooltip implies if you hover over it, it's your number of all-time rooms; i.e. the total number of rooms you've ever joined on chat.

The number opposite, in the right-hand corner, is your total message count.

Comment: Oh. SE has so many tooltips that mobile users can't access :P

Comment: As I always say: when in doubt, hover!